# how do you obtain a data set (around 10,000 data points) with a mean of 0 and standard deviation of 1.

Tags: time-series, distributions, normal-distribution, standard-deviation, density-function

I need a data set with a mean of 0 and stdv of 1. how do i get this?

Answer (score 7):

You could buy a copy of *[A Million Random Digits with 100,000 Normal Deviates](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0833030477)*.

Answer (score 1):

In R, for instance,

> rnorm(10000)

will give you ten thousand N(0,1) (pseudo)random observations. You could use `runif` to obtain uniform distributions, or any distribution of your choice by setting parameters so that mean is 0 and variance is 1.

Comment: You forgot to scale the results.

Comment: @Michael M: ??  I think rnorm will by default produce mena 0 and variance 1, runif of course will need to set parameters.

Comment: Not exactly. It will sample from a distribution with these parameters, but the specific sample will have a mean different of 0.

Comment: If this is what it was asked, then I guess there should be no problem  centering and standardizing the sample.